# Face other object using lerp in a coroutine

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to have a coroutine to use the lerp function and so far I managed to do so partially. The characters will turn their position to face the target object. However, I want the characters to move their rotation starting from their own while what is currently happening is their rotation is set to some abstract value like X=0 and then it will start rotating them from there.

What I want to do is simply turn the character to face another transform smoothly. Here's the code:

```
    public IEnumerator LookSlerpAt(Transform target, int seconds)
    {
        IsTurningHead = true;

        Vector3 relativePos = target.position - this.transform.position;

        Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos);
        float elapsedTime = 0f;
        float fraction = elapsedTime / seconds;

        while (elapsedTime <= seconds)
        {


            this.transform.rotation =  Quaternion.Lerp(target.rotation, lookRotation, fraction);
            print($"rotation:{this.transform.rotation}");
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            fraction = elapsedTime / seconds;

            yield return Time.deltaTime;
        }
        IsTurningHead = false;
    }
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: is `target` the same as `this.transform`?

Comment: I want "this" to loot at "target". I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to rotate smoothly to direction you could use that as coroutine: You specify the specified time to rotate and the velocity is automatically adjusted

```
    public IEnumerator RotateToDirection(Transform transform, Vector3 positionToLook, float timeToRotate)
    {
        var startRotation = transform.rotation;
        var direction = positionToLook - transform.position;
        var finalRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
        var t = 0f;
        while (t <= 1f)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime / timeToRotate;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startRotation, finalRotation, t);
            yield return null;
        }
        transform.rotation = finalRotation;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you , this works. The problem I had with my solution was that I did not save the initial rotation of the object and it was constantly updating. Also for reasons I don't understand it's better to "yield return null" instead of "yield return new WaitForSeconds(Time.deltaTime)"

Comment: "yield return new WaitForSeconds(Time.deltaTime)"  means i follow the actions after yield after waiting Time.deltaTime sec.  If you put that you have a light wait before each loop